# Create custom event log on remote server with PowerShell

Tags: .net, logging, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have an requirement where I need to create an custom event log on different server. I have the command to create the event log on local machine but need it for remote server. The command to create the event log on local machine is

```
powershell -command "if([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists('MySource')){Write 'Eventlog already exists'}else{[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource('MySource','MyCustomLog')}"
```

I want the same for the remote server.

Please paste the code if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the ASP.Net tag doing here? Because your powershell command is just pure .Net calls so doing it directly in ASP.Net would be easier. So why use powershell anyway?

Answer (score 2):

from your post on the Posh Comm

```
Invoke-command -computername server,server -scriptblock {if([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists('MySource')){Write 'Eventlog already exists'}else{[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource('MySource','MyCustomLog')}}
```

Or Shay Levy's more elegant:

```
New-EventLog -LogName application -Source MySource,MyCustomLog -ComputerName PC1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
Write-EventLog -LogName application -Source MySource -EntryType information -Message test -EventId 1234 -Computer PC1
```

Answer (score 0):

There also is a [CreateEventSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8wxca1h.aspx) with 3 arguments of which the last is the machine name. So that would make it:

```
if([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists('MySource', 'MyMachine'))
{
  Write 'Eventlog already exists'
}
else
{
  [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource('MySource','MyCustomLog', 'MyMachine')
}
```

Note that method with 3 arguments is marked obsolete. With some more work you could use the variant that takes an [EventSourceCreationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3.aspx) where you can also specify the machine name.